# Error during training neural network: input is not an integer between 1 and 100 although it is

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I imported my data from Matlab in matrix form and tried to use it in a neural network as given below but I get the error that says the input is not an integer between 1 and 100 although it is.

```
trainingData = 
  Flatten@Table[
    classinp[[i, All]] -> classout[[i, All]], {i, 1, 1750}];
validationData = 
 Flatten@Table[
   classinp[[i, All]] -> classout[[i, All]], {i, 1751, 2175}]

 net = 
  NetChain[{ LinearLayer[40], BatchNormalizationLayer[], 
    ElementwiseLayer[Ramp], LinearLayer[100], ElementwiseLayer[Ramp], 
    DropoutLayer[0.2], LinearLayer[100], DropoutLayer[0.2], 
    ElementwiseLayer[Ramp], LinearLayer[100], SoftmaxLayer[]}]

results = 
 NetTrain[net, trainingData, ValidationSet -> validationData , 
  BatchSize -> 256]
```

> First::nofirst: {} has zero length and no first element.
>
> NetTrain::encgenfail1: Could not encode input number 462 for port "Output": input is not an integer between 1 and 100. Please check the example.

I checked my output vector but there is no such case all the values are between 1 and 100. 
Also when I specify input and output sizes I received a similar error of:

> NetTrain::encgenfail1: Could not encode input number 462 for port "Output": <<868>>. Please check the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work if you explicitly define the [`LossFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LossFunction.html).

When a loss layer is chosen automatically for a port, the loss layer is based on the layer within the net whose output is connected to that port (in your case this is `LinearLayer[100]`). For a `SoftmaxLayer[]`, `CrossEntropyLossLayer["Index"]` is used by default. Then the target should be an integer between $1$ and $c$, or an array of such integers (in your case $c=$100). This explains the meaning of the error you get.

You probably need `"Probabilities"` (or `"Binary"`) instead of the default "Index" in `CrossEntropyLayer`, depending on the format of your training data. See for example the following code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
npoints = 50;
x1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.5], {npoints, 2}];
x2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 0.5], {npoints, 2}];
ListPlot[{x1, x2}, AxesLabel -> {"x1", "x2"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Some points belonging to two different classes]

```
net = NetInitialize@
  NetChain[{LinearLayer[10, "Input" -> 2], Ramp, LinearLayer[10], Ramp,
    LinearLayer[2], SoftmaxLayer[]}]
```

If I omit the `LossFunction`, I get the same error as you:

```
trainedNet = 
  NetTrain[net, 
   Join[x1, x2] -> 
    Join[ConstantArray[{1, 0}, npoints], 
         ConstantArray[{0, 1}, npoints]]];
```

> First::nofirst: {} has zero length and no first element.
>
> NetTrain::encgenfail1: Could not encode input number 57 for port
>   "Output": input is not an integer between 1 and 2. Please check the
>   example.

But if I explicitly (and correctly) set my `LossFunction`, then it works fine:

```
trainedNet = 
  NetTrain[net, 
   Join[x1, x2] -> 
    Join[ConstantArray[{1, 0}, npoints], 
     ConstantArray[{0, 1}, npoints]], 
   LossFunction -> CrossEntropyLossLayer["Binary"]];
```

The network is able to predict the right class:

```
Table[trainedNet[x1[[k]]]*100, {k, 1, npoints}]
{{100., 0.}, {100., 5.6806*10^-6}, {100., 0.}, {100., 0.}, {100., 
  0.}, {100., 8.03765*10^-28}, (* ... *) }
```